# Does websphere MQ create duplicate queues in a clustered environment

Tags: ibm-mq

If I want to set up Websphere MQ in a distributed environment (across 2 machines in a cluster), will the queues and topics(which I understand as physical storage spaces for messages) be created on both machines?

Or will the queues and topics be created on one machine only but the program (I guess it is called the websphere MQ broker) will be deployed on 2 machines and both the instances will  access the same queue and topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, MQ doesnot create duplicate queues in the cluster if you don't(manually).

Further, check whether your queue manager is a **Partial repository** or a **Full repository** for the cluster.

A partial repository will only contain information about its own objects whereas a full repository will have information about the objects of all queue managers in the cluster.

A cluster needs at least one full repository in it, and other partial repository can use this full repository for accessing objects of other queue managers.

But, the object information in full repository is just a list. Actual physical object will only be there in the queue manager where it was created.

Comment: Thank you. Can you also explain the difference between queue manager and websphere mq broker

Answer (score 3):

Cluster concept in WebSphere MQ is different from the traditional high availability (HA) clusters. In traditional HA cluster two systems access the same storage/data to provide HA feature. Both systems can be configured to be active at anytime and processing requests. You can also have a active/passive type of HA configuration.

Unlike traditional HA cluster, WebSphere MQ cluster is different. Two queue managers do not share the same storage/data. Each queue manager is unique. WebSphere MQ cluster is more suitable for workload balance than a HA. You can have a queue with same name in multiple queue managers in a MQ cluster and when messages are put, MQ cluster will load balance them to all queues in that cluster. It should be noted the messages in each instance of a queue in cluster are independent and are not shared. If for some reason one of the queue manager in a cluster goes down, then messages in that queue manager become unavailable till the queue manager comes back.

Are you aiming for workload balance or HA? If you are aim is to achieve HA, then you could look at the multi-instance queue manager feature of MQ or any other HA solutions. If you are aiming for workload balance then you can go for MQ clustering. You can also have a mix of mutli-instance queue manager and MQ clustering to achieve HA and workload balance.

Comment: Thanks. So when you say:'Two queue managers do not share the same storage/data' it means each queue maanger will have its own queue? I ask because the otehr answer states that the queues will not be duplicated.

Comment: Yes. A queue name Q1 in queue manager QM1 is totally different from another queue with the same name Q1 in another queue manager QM2. You can have a number of queues in a queue manager. A queue manager is a container for queues and manages the queues.